# How can I get past hitting "Continue" over and over?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, security

I am trying to get my Windows 10 to detect my 2nd hard drive. For reference, I have an Alienware M17xR3 with 2 hard drives. The main hard drive is `C:\` and the one I am trying to detect is `B:\`.

I found a way to do it [here](http://windowsreport.com/second-hard-drive-not-detected-windows-10/), but this led to the screenshot below. I can't sit here and click `Continue` for every single file that it can't find. Can someone help me find a workaround?

[image]

Comment: It looks like you're trying to change NTFS permissions. What exactly are you trying to set them to?

Comment: Is the B:\ drive from a computer that had Windows installed on it? You might need to format the drive first, which will erase all the data on the specified drive, and then try to connect the drive and assign a drive letter.

Comment: @Twisty All I'm trying to do is be able to read and modify my 2nd hard drive. Does that answer your question?

Comment: @ChristopherJohnson Yes, that 2nd drive had Windows on it. But I just had this working about a year ago, not sure what happened. I was able to open up that drive and modify its contents at will. Several Windows 10 patches, I am no longer able to do so.

Comment: @whatwhatwhat Just to confirm, you *don't* want to erase the contents of the drive; correct?

Comment: @Twisty Correct.

Comment: You need to use the TAKEOWN and ICACLS commands from a command prompt to avoid the continue prompts. I would post an answer but won't be able to quickly and maybe you can figure it out in the meantime.

Comment: See the proposed duplicate. It has the commands you need.  Good luck.